# .htaccess not working in Apache EC2 Linux Server

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-ec2, httpd.conf

mode rewrite is on   (checked with info.php test
AllowOveride All in etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file

inserted .htaccess in  /var/www/html

```
RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /wordpress/
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
```

( want to redirect from home page to wordpress subdirectory ...)

restarted Apache

```
service httpd restart
```

but Apache home page displayed ... on http://mywpblog.net

wordpress home page  when request is http://mywpblog.net/wordpress

Did I miss anything ?  ( dummy on EC2/httpd )  thanks

Comment: the root site  http://mywpblog.net  to the wordpress directory http://mywpblog.net/wordpress ..  I re-tested w a modified .htaccess ( see my answer ) and it works ...

Answer (score 3):

wrong .htaccess !
should  be ( in /var/www/html directory )

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Turn on rewrites.
 RewriteEngine on

# Don't apply to URLs that go to existing files or folders.
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Only apply to URLs that aren't already under /wp.
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress/

# Rewrite all those to insert /wordpress
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wordpress/$1

# Redirect the root folder.
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?yodojodo.net$
 RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wordpress/ [L]
 </IfModule>
```